# Filtering with unrelated entities using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

How can we do this in EF,

```
Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
vmJob.MatchJob = db.Jobs.Where(p=>p.Skills in (member.Skills));
```

Its just like a job matching function.. wherein the member has a skills, and a job requires skills.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

djcohen66 was close. When both are collections, you can use `.Any` on the candidate collection.

```
var member = db.Members.Find(id);
var memberSkillIds = member.Skills.Select(ms => ms.SkillId).ToList();
var jobs = db.Jobs.Where(j => j.Skills.Any(js => memberSkillIds.Contains(js.SkillId)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Member member = db.Members.Find(id); 
var memberSkills = member.Skills.Select(ms=>ms.SkillId).ToArray(); //assumes a skill has a skill id.
var matchJobs = db.Jobs.Where(mj=> memberSkills.Contains(mj.Skill));
```

That should return jobs where the job.Skills includes the member's skills.

Comment: Hi,.. i don't have a Skill property on my Job instead a collection of Skill.. because a Job can be related to multiple skills..

so i got an error on the list line.. (mj.Skill).

tnx